# How to create list comprehension of absolute paths

Tags: python, syntax, list-comprehension

All I want to do is create a list whose elements are each the full path to each of the files in a particular directory.

```
import os

dirname = "/Users/marcusj/test/pngfiles"
print dirname
fullnames = []
fullnames = [for f in os.listdir(dirname):
   (os.path.join(dirname, f))]
print fullnames
```

When I'm told I have a syntax error:
    python2.7 test.py
      File "test.py", line 7
        for f in os.listdir(dirname):
      ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format for list comprehension differs somewhat from that of a `for` loop.

Replace:

```
fullnames = [for f in os.listdir(dirname): (os.path.join(dirname, f))]
```

With:

```
fullnames = [os.path.join(dirname, f) for f in os.listdir(dirname)]
```